# How to enable or disable or enable a task in task Scheduler through vb6.0 code

Tags: vb6

I want to enable or disable a task in task Scheduler in windows operating system through vb6.0 code. I have made a task in task Scheduler. Now I want to enable or disable this task from vb6.0 code.

Any Solution would be the great help.

Comment: What Windows versions are you targeting?

Comment: Currently I have installed VB6 setup on windows 7 OS

Comment: That means that my answer should work on your development PC. Do you need this to run on pre-Vista machines?

Comment: I provide my MSI(SetUp Installer) to other user which will have different OS then It will work ?

Comment: If they are Windows Vista and above, yes.

Comment: Can you please mention which OS comes after Windows Vista?

Comment: Windows 7. Please do the mininum of research.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes you are targeting Windows Vista / 2008 Server and above.

You first need to add a reference to the taskschd.dll library:

[image: Adding TaskScheduler to References]

In the following code, the GetTask() helper function uses the folder (which is `vbNullString` for the top level folder), and the actual "task_name".

[image]

You can then use the Enabled property of the returning task to enable/disable it.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim oTask           As TaskScheduler.IRegisteredTask

    Set oTask = GetTask(vbNullString, "task_name")

    oTask.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Function GetTask(ByRef in_sFolderName As String, ByRef in_sTaskName As String) As TaskScheduler.IRegisteredTask

    Dim oTaskScheduler  As TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler
    Dim oFolder         As TaskScheduler.ITaskFolder

    Set oTaskScheduler = New TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler
    oTaskScheduler.Connect

    Set oFolder = oTaskScheduler.GetFolder(in_sFolderName)

    Set GetTask = oFolder.GetTask(in_sTaskName)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This vbScript procedure run on every windows system if powershell is installed.

```
Sub edit_task_stat(taskname, status)
    'taskname is Case Sensitive
    Dim stDic, tShl, comd, stat

    If VarType(status) = 2 Then status = Cstr(status)
    If (VarType(status) = 8) and (not IsNumeric(status)) Then
        stat = LCase(status)
    Else
        stat = status
    End If
    set stDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    stDic.add "0", "Disable"
    stDic.add "1", "Enable"
    stDic.add "disable", "Disable"
    stDic.add "enable", "Enable"
    stDic.add "off", "Disable"
    stDic.add "on", "Enable"
    comd = "-executionpolicy Bypass -Command " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(38) & Chr(32) & stDic(stat) & "-ScheduledTask -TaskName '" & taskname & Chr(39) & Chr(34) & Chr(34)
    Set tShl = CreateObject("Shell.Application")  
    tShl.ShellExecute "powershell", comd, "", "runas", 0
    Set tShl = Nothing
End Sub
```

To Disable Sheduled Task: the second parameter can also be: "0" or "disable"

```
Call edit_task_stat("YourTaskName", "Off")
```

To Enable Sheduled Task: the second parameter can also be: "1" or "enable"

```
Call edit_task_stat("YourTaskName", "On")
```